# Adjusting to ASP from PHP

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc

I'm in the process of learning ASP.NET and I'm having a few difficulties with certain things. The main difficulty I have right now is accessing data from a database. Usually in PHP in the model I'd just write an SQL query for a specific model function and then that'd query the DB and return the results I want to the calling controller. Is doing this fine in ASP MVC? And if so how do you do it? The tutorial I was following started using scaffolding and I want to avoid that as I want to fully understand how it all fits together.

Comment: Unsure what you refer to as scaffolding, so perhaps a [good place to start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.110).aspx) hth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself started in PHP and gradually moved to .NET. The way I manage my database is via Entity Framework. I know it may sound like you've got to learn yet another useless thing, but it is actually very simple. If you just want to learn the concept: use code first approach.

This is how it works: you create a bunch of models (that you will need anyway its called Model-View-Controller for a reason) that are nothing but objects. Those models are used to build your database. So you no longer need to set up the database manually (e.g. phpMyAdmin). It sounds quite amazing but that's how it works and then you use LINQ (or LINQ-to-SQL) to get queries.

This an example of a LINQ-to-SQL query:

```
var query = from u in dbContext.User where u.UserID == 1 select u;
```

This will come useful later on as well when you want to validate information etc. Here is a great starting tutorial (just watch the first 4 of those videos):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7713GBhi4k&list=PL6n9fhu94yhUPBSX-E2aJCnCR3-_6zBZx

Moving from PHP to .NET is a big move, but it is really worth it.

Good Luck!

Comment: just a curiosity, what are benefits passing from php to asp.net. what does asp.net has that php don't?